# SonarQube : C# files not analyzed with the new version (7.2)

Tags: c#, sonarqube, azure-devops, sonarqube-scan

I've recently upgraded our SonarQube server from a 5.x version to a 7.2 version. I've launched the database migration like it is described in the documentation, and the server seems correctly upgraded.
The projects was correctly analyzed with the previous version of SonarQube, but now with the 7.2 version I have these following error messages :

```
2018-08-16T07:43:28.8310428Z ##[error]08:43:28.822 WARN: Property missing: 'sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.
2018-08-16T07:43:28.8311036Z 08:43:28.822 WARN: Property missing: 'sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.
2018-08-16T07:43:28.8313994Z ##[error]08:43:28.822 WARN: No roslyn issues report not found for this project.
2018-08-16T07:43:28.8315503Z 08:43:28.822 WARN: No roslyn issues report not found for this project.
```

I have also a lot of error messages like this :

```
2018-08-16T07:43:27.8889117Z ##[error]08:43:27.885 WARN: File 'S:\VSTS\_work\123\s\WSDAL\WSDAL\WSDAL.csproj' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
2018-08-16T07:43:27.8889699Z 08:43:27.885 WARN: File 'S:\VSTS\_work\123\s\WSDAL\WSDAL\WSDAL.csproj' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
2018-08-16T07:43:27.8890597Z ##[error]08:43:27.885 WARN: File 'S:\VSTS\_work\123\s\WSDAL\WSDAL.nsi' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
2018-08-16T07:43:27.8891507Z 
2018-08-16T07:43:27.8893986Z ##[error]08:43:27.885 WARN: File 'S:\VSTS\_work\123\s\WSDAL\WSDAL.sln' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
2018-08-16T07:43:27.8896320Z 08:43:27.885 WARN: File 'S:\VSTS\_work\123\s\WSDAL\WSDAL.sln' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
```

The analyze is launched from VSTS with the SonarQube plugin and with the additional parameters :

```
sonar.sources=.
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.language=cs
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=*.Test
sonar.exclusions=UITests/**,UnitTests/**
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

With the "verbose" option, I have these informations :

```
2018-08-16T07:43:18.7068176Z ==============================================================================
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5912144Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "S:\VSTS\_work\_tasks\SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055\4.3.0\sonar-scanner\bin\sonar-scanner.bat"
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5912599Z INFO: Scanner configuration file: S:\VSTS\_work\_tasks\SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055\4.3.0\sonar-scanner\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5912936Z INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5913156Z 08:43:19.166 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.2.0.1227
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5913401Z 08:43:19.166 INFO: Java 1.8.0_181 Oracle Corporation (32-bit)
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5913632Z 08:43:19.166 INFO: Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 x86
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5913862Z 08:43:19.291 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5914074Z 08:43:19.291 DEBUG: keyStore type is : jks
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5914289Z 08:43:19.291 DEBUG: keyStore provider is : 
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5915184Z 08:43:19.291 DEBUG: init keystore
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5915409Z 08:43:19.291 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5915658Z 08:43:19.432 DEBUG: Create: C:\Users\yannick\.sonar\cache
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5915896Z 08:43:19.432 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\yannick\.sonar\cache
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5916159Z 08:43:19.447 DEBUG: Create: C:\Users\yannick\.sonar\cache\_tmp
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5916398Z 08:43:19.447 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5916636Z 08:43:19.447 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5916872Z 08:43:19.447 DEBUG: Download: http://SonarQubeServer:9999/batch/index
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5917121Z 08:43:19.494 DEBUG: Get bootstrap completed
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5917341Z 08:43:19.510 DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5917572Z 08:43:19.510 DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5917783Z 08:43:19.510 DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5918014Z 08:43:19.510 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5918225Z 08:43:19.525 INFO: SonarQube server 7.2.1
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5918575Z 08:43:19.525 INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5918833Z 08:43:19.525 DEBUG: Work directory: S:\VSTS\_work\123\s\.scannerwork
2018-08-16T07:43:19.5919082Z 08:43:19.525 DEBUG: Execution execute
2018-08-16T07:43:19.7662081Z 08:43:19.760 INFO: Publish mode
2018-08-16T07:43:19.9390673Z 08:43:19.932 INFO: Load global settings
2018-08-16T07:43:20.0043807Z 08:43:19.978 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/api/settings/values.protobuf | time=46ms
2018-08-16T07:43:20.0292709Z 08:43:20.025 INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=93ms
2018-08-16T07:43:20.0369335Z 08:43:20.025 INFO: Server id: EsA58sX698qSes654w
2018-08-16T07:43:20.0492805Z 08:43:20.041 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\yannick\.sonar\cache
2018-08-16T07:43:20.4268501Z 08:43:20.416 INFO: Load/download plugins
2018-08-16T07:43:20.4271693Z 08:43:20.416 INFO: Load plugins index
2018-08-16T07:43:20.4353642Z 08:43:20.432 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/api/plugins/installed | time=16ms
2018-08-16T07:43:20.4895763Z 08:43:20.479 INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=63ms
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5094751Z 08:43:20.494 INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=78ms
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5569127Z 08:43:20.541 DEBUG: Plugins:
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5575528Z 08:43:20.541 DEBUG:   * SonarPython 1.10.0.2131 (python)
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5575997Z 08:43:20.541 DEBUG:   * SonarGo 1.1.0.1612 (go)
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5576307Z 08:43:20.541 DEBUG:   * Svn 1.8.0.1168 (scmsvn)
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5576629Z 08:43:20.541 DEBUG:   * SonarJS 4.2.1.6529 (javascript)
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5576929Z 08:43:20.541 DEBUG:   * SonarC# 7.3.0.5690 (csharp)
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5577237Z 08:43:20.541 DEBUG:   * SonarJava 5.6.0.15032 (java)
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5577533Z 08:43:20.541 DEBUG:   * LDAP 2.2.0.608 (ldap)
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5577842Z 08:43:20.541 DEBUG:   * Git 1.4.1.1128 (scmgit)
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5578172Z 08:43:20.541 DEBUG:   * SonarFlex 2.4.0.1222 (flex)
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5578472Z 08:43:20.541 DEBUG:   * SonarXML 1.5.1.1452 (xml)
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5578780Z 08:43:20.541 DEBUG:   * SonarPHP 2.14.0.3569 (php)
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5579084Z 08:43:20.541 DEBUG:   * SonarTS 1.7.0.2893 (typescript)
2018-08-16T07:43:20.5720186Z 08:43:20.557 INFO: Loaded core extensions: 
2018-08-16T07:43:20.9135176Z 08:43:20.900 INFO: Process project properties
2018-08-16T07:43:20.9203852Z 08:43:20.916 DEBUG: Process project properties (done) | time=16ms
2018-08-16T07:43:20.9398896Z 08:43:20.932 INFO: Load project repositories
2018-08-16T07:43:21.4140553Z 08:43:21.400 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/batch/project.protobuf?key=project_key | time=468ms
2018-08-16T07:43:21.5284145Z 08:43:21.525 INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=593ms
2018-08-16T07:43:21.6615142Z 08:43:21.652 DEBUG: Available languages:
2018-08-16T07:43:21.6616619Z 08:43:21.652 DEBUG:   * Python => "py"
2018-08-16T07:43:21.6616940Z 08:43:21.652 DEBUG:   * Go => "go"
2018-08-16T07:43:21.6617249Z 08:43:21.652 DEBUG:   * JavaScript => "js"
2018-08-16T07:43:21.6617534Z 08:43:21.652 DEBUG:   * C# => "cs"
2018-08-16T07:43:21.6617827Z 08:43:21.652 DEBUG:   * Java => "java"
2018-08-16T07:43:21.6618165Z 08:43:21.652 DEBUG:   * Flex => "flex"
2018-08-16T07:43:21.6618457Z 08:43:21.652 DEBUG:   * XML => "xml"
2018-08-16T07:43:21.6618733Z 08:43:21.652 DEBUG:   * PHP => "php"
2018-08-16T07:43:21.6619030Z 08:43:21.652 DEBUG:   * TypeScript => "ts"
2018-08-16T07:43:21.6684968Z 08:43:21.666 INFO: Load quality profiles
2018-08-16T07:43:21.6864786Z 08:43:21.682 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?projectKey=project_key | time=16ms
2018-08-16T07:43:21.6911948Z 08:43:21.682 INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=16ms
2018-08-16T07:43:21.7055123Z 08:43:21.697 INFO: Load active rules
2018-08-16T07:43:21.7292078Z 08:43:21.713 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=cs-sonar-way-40297&p=1&ps=500 | time=16ms
2018-08-16T07:43:21.8274962Z 08:43:21.822 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=java-sonar-way-05385&p=1&ps=500 | time=62ms
2018-08-16T07:43:21.8578910Z 08:43:21.854 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=TR5ERPD85D3EEE&p=1&ps=500 | time=16ms
2018-08-16T07:43:21.8703088Z 08:43:21.869 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=ER6DFX8I65d&p=1&ps=500 | time=15ms
2018-08-16T07:43:21.8942153Z 08:43:21.885 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=DE5DD5OPP67DD&p=1&ps=500 | time=16ms
2018-08-16T07:43:21.9363457Z 08:43:21.916 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=js-sonar-way-28294&p=1&ps=500 | time=31ms
2018-08-16T07:43:21.9594956Z 08:43:21.947 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=DDDD5FECDVSDQ&p=1&ps=500 | time=15ms
2018-08-16T07:43:21.9782101Z 08:43:21.963 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=DSCDSQCDSQCD&p=1&ps=500 | time=16ms
2018-08-16T07:43:21.9989077Z 08:43:21.994 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=DSQDFSQCDSQCDS&p=1&ps=500 | time=15ms
2018-08-16T07:43:22.0113544Z 08:43:22.010 INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=313ms
2018-08-16T07:43:22.0179051Z 08:43:22.010 INFO: Load metrics repository
2018-08-16T07:43:22.0256465Z 08:43:22.010 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/api/metrics/search?f=name,description,direction,qualitative,custom&ps=500&p=1 | time=0ms
2018-08-16T07:43:22.0365801Z 08:43:22.025 INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=15ms
2018-08-16T07:43:22.0427992Z 08:43:22.041 DEBUG: SCM Step is disabled by configuration
2018-08-16T07:43:22.0493558Z 08:43:22.041 INFO: Project key: project_key
2018-08-16T07:43:22.0494085Z 08:43:22.041 INFO: Project base dir: S:\VSTS\_work\123\s
2018-08-16T07:43:22.0503378Z 08:43:22.041 DEBUG: Start recursive analysis of project modules
2018-08-16T07:43:22.0511419Z 08:43:22.041 INFO: -------------  Scan project
2018-08-16T07:43:22.2015446Z 08:43:22.197 INFO: Load server rules
2018-08-16T07:43:22.2897220Z 08:43:22.275 DEBUG: GET 200 http://SonarQubeServer:9999/api/rules/list.protobuf | time=78ms
2018-08-16T07:43:22.3396578Z 08:43:22.307 INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=110ms
2018-08-16T07:43:22.3479690Z 08:43:22.338 INFO: Base dir: S:\VSTS\_work\123\s
2018-08-16T07:43:22.3480392Z 08:43:22.338 INFO: Working dir: S:\VSTS\_work\123\s\.scannerwork
2018-08-16T07:43:22.3491581Z 08:43:22.338 INFO: Source paths: .
2018-08-16T07:43:22.3493099Z 08:43:22.338 INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
2018-08-16T07:43:22.4591820Z 08:43:22.447 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Python were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.py : **/*.py
2018-08-16T07:43:22.4592818Z 08:43:22.447 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Go were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.go : **/*.go
2018-08-16T07:43:22.4593300Z 08:43:22.447 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language JavaScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.js : **/*.js,**/*.jsx,**/*.vue
2018-08-16T07:43:22.4593740Z 08:43:22.447 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language C# were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.cs : **/*.cs
2018-08-16T07:43:22.4594149Z 08:43:22.447 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Java were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.java : **/*.java,**/*.jav
2018-08-16T07:43:22.4594594Z 08:43:22.447 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Flex were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.flex : **/*.as
2018-08-16T07:43:22.4594992Z 08:43:22.447 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language XML were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.xml : **/*.xml,**/*.xsd,**/*.xsl
2018-08-16T07:43:22.4595455Z 08:43:22.447 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language PHP were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.php : **/*.php,**/*.php3,**/*.php4,**/*.php5,**/*.phtml,**/*.inc
2018-08-16T07:43:22.4595960Z 08:43:22.447 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language TypeScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.ts : **/*.ts,**/*.tsx
2018-08-16T07:43:22.4596303Z 08:43:22.447 INFO: Language is forced to cs
2018-08-16T07:43:22.4682965Z 08:43:22.463 DEBUG: Initializers : 
2018-08-16T07:43:22.4691697Z 08:43:22.463 INFO: Index files
```

I really don't understand what is the problem. I've tried to find a solution on internet, but without success.
Any idea or solution about these issues please ?

Comment: You also updated the Sonar Scanner called in sonar-scanner.bat? According to your log you're still using an old version (3.2.0.1227). Should be something like SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.3.1.1372. To be used on SonarQube 6.7 or newer. See https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild.

Comment: It's automatically done with the  VSTS plugin dedicated to the sonar analysis : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS I can't do anything with the bat file.

Comment: OK, so one area less to investigate.

Comment: I think that the issue is certainly due to the mode used to run the analysis. I will try to change the mode "Use the standalone scanner" with the mode "Integrate with MSbuild"

Comment: Did you try to run without the sonar.langauge=cs flag?

Comment: why the sonar.language=cs should be a problem ? I tried to change the mode "Use the standalone scanner" with the mode "Integrate with MSbuild"and it's better (just less files analyzed)